# Spark: Split is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, linux-disk-free

Below is my code from Spark 1.6. I am trying to convert it to Spark 2.3 but I am getting error for using split.

Spark 1.6 code:

```
val file = spark.textFile(args(0))
val mapping = file.map(_.split('/t')).map(a => a(1))
mapping.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
```

Spark 2.3 code:

```
val file = spark.read.text(args(0))
val mapping = file.map(_.split('/t')).map(a => a(1)) //Getting Error Here
mapping.write.text(args(1))
```

Error Message:

```
value split is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike `spark.textFile` which returns a `RDD`, 
[spark.read.text](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@text(path:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) returns a `DataFrame` which is essentially a `RDD[Row]`.  You could perform `map` with a partial function as shown in the following example:

```
// /path/to/textfile:
// a    b   c
// d    e   f

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val df = spark.read.text("/path/to/textfile")

df.map{ case Row(s: String) => s.split("\\t") }.map(_(1)).show
// +-----+
// |value|
// +-----+
// |    b|
// |    e|
// +-----+
```

Comment: You can also `df.as[String].map(line => line.split(...)).show()`.

Comment: df.as[String] only works if the strings are small. Although there is a limit that can be increased this does not work well with long strings....